# What is reduction variable? Could anyone give me some examples?

Tags: variables, llvm, reduction

What is reduction variable? 
  Could anyone give me some examples?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a simple example in a C-like language of computing the sum of an array:

```
int x = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    x += a[i];
}
```

In this example,

- `i` is an *induction variable* - in each iteration it changes by some constant. It can be `+1` (as in the above example) or `*2` or `/3` etc., but the key is that in all the iterations the number is the same.

  In other words, in each iteration `i_new = i_old op constant`, where `op` is `+`, `*`, etc., and neither `op` nor `constant` change between iterations.
- `x` is a *reduction variable* - it accumulates data from one iteration to the next. It always has some initialization (`x = 0` in this case), and while the data accumulated can be different in each iteration, the operator remains the same.

  In other words, in each iteration `x_new = x_old op data`, and `op` remains the same in all iterations (though `data` may change).

In many languages [there's a special syntax for performing something like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_(higher-order_function)) - often called a "fold" or "reduce" or "accumulate" (and it has other names) - but in the context of LLVM IR, an induction variable will be represented by a phi node in a loop between a binary operation inside the loop and the initialization value before it.

Commutative* operations in reduction variables (such as addition) are particularly interesting for an optimizing compiler because they appear to show a stronger dependency between iterations than there really is; for instance the above example could be rewritten into a vectorized form - adding, say, 4 numbers at a time, and followed by a small loop to sum the final vector into a single value.

<sub>* there are actually more conditions that the reduction variable has to fulfill before a vectorization like this can be applied, but that's really outside the scope here</sub>