# how to get the index of the loop using looppass in llvm

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I am a newbie to llvm and clang. I wanted to try out with loop pass and find the loop details like its index, corresponding operation performed within the loop etc. I am really not able to understand anything from the documentation. I could count the number of loops by making a counter inside runOnLoop() function. Can somebody please help me in starting the things??

Answer (score 0):

It's called [the loop's induction variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14955912/242762). The basic way to find those are via

```
loop->getCanonicalInductionVariable()
```

But that of course only works for *canonical* induction variables (start at 0, increment by 1).

Comment: what about the operations getting performed in the loop? Like some array getting accessed. How can we do that?

Comment: @user2699535 I didn't understand the question. Everything inside the loop's basic blocks is part of the loop.